# How to create ldap user in ibm mq?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to integrate mq docker container authentication with LDAP. can any one tell me how to configure LDAP from MQ console and add user with restricted privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood relationship of IBM MQ and LDAP.

Historically MQ would look to the underlying OS (operating system) for user and group information.  When MQ v8 came out it had a new feature called connection authentication, you could configure MQ to authenticate the user and password via the OS or via LDAP.  If it was configured with LDAP it was initially only providing the username, you still had to have the user configured on the OS for MQ to find group memberships.  Later this LDAP support expanded to be able to also get a user's group membership from LDAP.

To summarize, MQ is not a LDAP server it is just a LDAP client in this configuration.

You will need to connect to a LDAP server (for example a Microsoft Active Directory controller), this is where the user would be added.  You would then configure the permissions you want that user to have via the MQ console.

How to point to a LDAP server is not a simple answer as many of the parameters you need to specify depend on the LDAP structure.  You should go back and read the knowledge center for IBM MQ and read it again, and then attempt to set it up.  If you still have problems come back and ask a NEW question with more specifics on what you have tried and what errors you have received.

Comment: Sorry I confused you.....my intention is to enable manage user(ldap) from MQ console. ie, I can give RBAC for mq. Can I achieve it from MQ console?

Comment: Please review the last paragraph of my answer.   Your question is too broad to answer with out more details.